# Detect Particle command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a map and I want to have particles that gives certain effects to surrounding entities. I was thinking about using the /execute detect command but it only detects blocks! Is there any way to detect the particles and then run a command?

Comment: Afaik, particles are neither entities or blocks and also afaik its not possible to detect them, and if so would be with plugins and would be very difficult

Comment: But I saw it once in a vanilla Minecraft command video!

Comment: @JP2K It is still not possible. Whatever the video was doing was either not vanilla or smoke and mirrors. It would help if you provided a link to the video so we can clarify what exactly was done.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yw_hr00tQx0                                              As you can see it hurt the wolf! Please explain as it whould help a lot!

Comment: Um if you were using invisible Armor Stands it would be very possible. To testfor a armor stand with a certain name

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating particles then checking for those particles, try creating particles and checking for entities where you are creating the particles.

Have one command block creating your particles at x, y, z then have another checking for an entity at x, y, z instead of looking for the particles. Then apply the desired effect to any entities it detects.

Answer (score 0):

well, you could include a recourcepack in the map and re-texture a block with the texture of the block the floor.

For example, a hallway made of iron blocks, place stone where an iron block is supost to go and run the command /execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone 0 /say 1
and replace /say 1 with whatever command you want, just play the particles over the stone.